# Set an NTP server on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, client-server, beagleboneblack, ntp

I have a Beaglebone connected to my Windows 7 PC via Ethernet. I need current time on the embedded board for logging purposes. I used to use battery with an RTC chip to keep time there but I thought that an easier way to do this, since I'm connected to my PC anyway, is to download time on start-up.

I would just use the installed NTP client on Beaglebone. The problem is that I have no internet there and it is not necessary, so I cannot connect to the NTP server on the internet. I can though, connect to a server that would be running on the connected Windows 7 PC.

Is there an easy way to configure an NTP server on a Windows 7 machine?

Answer (score 3):

On Win7 (NTP server):
The following two registry changes are required:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\W32Time\AnnounceFlags = 5
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\W32Time\TimeProviders\NtpServer = 1
```

Ensure "Windows Time" service is set to Automatic.

Also, ensure UDP inbound to port 123 is permitted

Answer (score 1):

If time precision is important for you logging purposes and you have a budget so I would like you to take a look at [NTS server](http://nts.softros.com/server.html), it also hosts NTP/SNTP and gives <1ms time sync precision on the LAN while Windows w32time has around 30 secs inaccuracy.